# splitting and merging of large files under windows AND Mac

Tags: linux, windows, mac

I found some good answers for how to split and merge large files in Mac or Linux. But is it possible to split files in one OS and then merge them in another OS?
To clarify more, I am looking for a way to split a large file using terminal on Mac and then be able to merge the same parts on Mac or on Windows or on Linux through terminal command line.
Any solution?
I know some applications do this like 7z or WINRAR but I am looking for a command-line solution not an application-driven solution. Thanks.

Comment: No offesnse but what does Linux have to do with this question?  Mac is not Linux.  Not even close.  Have you looked at 7z?  It is universal.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I just edited my question. Thanks for reminding. I am just looking for a universal or cross-platform solution. I know there are some applications doing this like 7z, but I am looking for a command-line solution not an application-driven solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why differentiate command line from 'an application'? They will both be using the same underlying libs. You need to find what libs are available across all platforms, either built-in or freely available.

Comment: 7z has a command line silly!  I use it on Windows, Mac, and Linux! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know a cross-platform tool for splitting and merging large files. But only for Windows ISO image.

You can check out it here:  https://wimlib.net/

For reference:

> wimlib is an open source, cross-platform library for creating,
> extracting, and modifying Windows Imaging (WIM) archives.  It allows
> storing various Windows-specific metadata, allows storing multiple
> "images" in a single archive, automatically deduplicates all file
> contents, and supports optional solid compression to get a better
> compression ratio. wimlib and its command-line frontend wimlib-imagex
> provide a free and cross-platform alternative to Microsoft's WIMGAPI,
> ImageX, and DISM.